# preprocess data sets for Tensorflow highlevel estimators

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I'm coming from a Scikit Learn background.
I'm having difficulty understanding how to preprocess data sets for Tensorflow.

I'm trying to implement svm with the iris data set.
If I have two numpy arrays, one containing a list of the features, and the other containing the list of the labels, which functions would I use to create the classifier?

```
estimator = SVM(
    example_id_column='example_id',
    feature_columns=[real_feature_column, sparse_feature_column],
    l2_regularization=10.0)
```

I'm assuming the example_id_column would be

```
example_id_column  = '0,1,2'
```

I'm not sure about how to attain the feature_columns

Answer (score 0):

I think the most effective way is using the `TFRecords` files. There's a [comprehensive tutorial](https://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/) available that's still mostly relevant, too. This also has the advantage of letting you define a lot more of your pipeline as part of the graph, being able to do concurrent reads from the source files, and not needing to fit your dataset in memory. It's definitely worth the effort.